# Angular Expression Errors Ng-Bind-Html

Tags: angularjs

I am having a problem with my `ng-bind-html` expression, which may stem from the fact that I am not using curly braces, but instead using `**` and `@@` because I am using my angular in a laravel template, as such, I can't use curly braces. I get a lexer error in the `ng-bind-html`. Here is my code:

My app (that sets the alternate start and end symbols):

```
var app = angular.module('Mole', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'], function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('**');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('@@');
    });
```

My controller:

```
 $scope.slides= [{

    id:1,
    image:"",
    content: $sce.trustAsHtml("<div id='chartContainer'></div>")},
    {
    id:2,
    image:"",
    content:""
    },

    {
    id:3,
    image:"",
    content:""
    }],
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="carouselContainer">
    <uib-carousel interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
      <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active" index="slide.id">
        <img ng-src="**slide.img@@" style="margin:auto;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>Slide **slide.id@@</h4>
          <div ng-bind-html="**slide.content@@"></div> <!--Error Here-->
        </div>
      </uib-slide>
    </uib-carousel>
    </div>
```

Comment: `ng-bind-html` don't need interpolatio directive to evaluate values, it works without it like `ng-bind-html="slide.content"` should work

Comment: @PankajParkar already tried that, it didn't inject my HTML content when I did that, it literally just echoed out "slide.content"

Comment: What is your error? You do not import `ngSanitize` in your module, so i don't think `$sce` is defined for you.

Comment: It is defined, in the controller. I just didn't include those injections. My error is: `Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 15-15 [@] in expression [**slide.content@@].`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok!

If you want to dynamically drop trusted HTML into the DOM, you have to bind the SCE function to the scope, and call it directly in the template. Here is a sample controller that I've taken from the linked plunker.

```
app.controller("Controller", function($scope, $sce){
  $scope.trustAsHtml = function(string) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
    };
  $scope.slides= {
      id: 1,
      content:'<div id="YourContainer">Binding :)</div>'
    };

});
```

and in the template:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller" id="carouselContainer">
      **slides.id@@
      <div ng-href="**slides.id@@" ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(slides.content)"></div>
</div>
```

[Here is a plunkr!](https://plnkr.co/edit/5QkkaeT9UINCs1YCfJbU?p=preview)

You can inspect the element to see YourContainer was carried with the tag as well.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but if you look at your result, which is the same as I am getting, you will see the `id` of the `<div>` does not get passed, which is the key piece of content I need. Why is this the case? :(

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood your goal. I've updated my answer with something that should accomplish what you want.